# Is the usage of 'apart' correct here?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> **Apart** from the crash issue in the software, we don't have any other issue.

What I want to say here is that except the crash issue in the software, there is no other issue. Is the usage of apart appropriate here?

Comment: Yes, it is. Another option is "other than"

Comment: And as such you could write "We don't have any issue *with* the software **other than/apart from**  the crash issue." I would begin with the good news.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is, up to a point. The sentence is a bit awkward.

Another way of expressing the same thought, if that's what you want to call it, would be:

> Apart from the crash issue, the software is problem-free.

(Avoid redundancy. If "problem-free" isn't elegant enough for you, you might want to give one of its cousins a shot: blameless, impeccable, faultless, flawless, foolproof, utterly reliable, etc).